# MAS SDK iOS use of location framework

Tags: ios

Is  iOS-MAS-Proximity codee repository using Core eLocation services ? I am not using Core location service in my code base bt after integrating this repo I got warning from Apple store to add Locationbased usage string.
Can someone comment if they use LocationService in IOS ?

https://github.com/CAAPIM/iOS-MAS-Proximity